# Why do identifiers of the form ${\tt c}k\$nnn$ appear in the rules returned by my function?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to define a function, `PolynomialInterpolation` to find the coefficients of a polynomial interpolation function. My trial is as shown below:

```
PolynomialInterpolation[tb_, tf_, θb_, θf_, θbDot1_, θfDot1_, θbDot2_, θfDot2_] := 
  Module[
    {InterpolationResult, u, θ, θDot1, θDot2, c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, PolynomialParameter},
    θ[t_] := c0 + c1 t + c2 t^2 + c3 t^3 + c4 t^4 + c5 t^5;
    θDot1[t_] := D[θ[u], u] /. u -> t;
    θDot2[t_] := D[θ[u], {u, 2}] /. u -> t;
    PolynomialParameter = 
      Solve[{
        θ[tb] == θb, 
        θ[tf] == θf, 
        θDot1[tb] == θbDot1, 
        θDot1[tf] == θfDot1,
        θDot2[tb] == θbDot2, 
        θDot2[tf] == θfDot2
        },
        {c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}]
  ]
```

However, when I use my function `PolynomialInterpolatio`, it returns:

```
PolynomialInterpolation[0, 5, 30, 75, 0, 0, 5, - 5]
```

> ```
> {{c0$698 -> 30, c1$698 -> 0, c2$698 -> 5/2, c3$698 -> 8/5, 
>   c4$698 -> -(29/50), c5$698 -> 29/625}}
> ```

So my question is why does the result contain variables with `$` in their names?

Comment: see [How Modules Work](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/HowModulesWork.html)

Comment: Try `Block` instead of `Module`...

Comment: For reference, there is the built in *Mathematica* function [`InterpolatingPolynomial[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html).

Comment: @rasher,thank you,it return right result when I use `Block[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although replacng `Module` with `Block` can deal with this problem, it is fussy and inconvenient. As @J. W. Perry said, the *built-in* *Mathematica* function  [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html)

**OP's solution**

```
 polyInterpolation[tb_, tf_, θb_, θf_, θbDot1_, θfDot1_, θbDot2_, θfDot2_] := 
  Block[
   {InterpolationResult, u, θ, θDot1, θDot2, c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5,  
    PolynomialParameter},
   θ[t_] := c0 + c1 t + c2 t^2 + c3 t^3 + c4 t^4 + c5 t^5;
   θDot1[t_] := D[θ[u], u] /. u -> t;
   θDot2[t_] := D[θ[u], {u, 2}] /. u -> t;
   PolynomialParameter = 
    Solve[{
      θ[tb] == θb, 
      θ[tf] == θf, 
      θDot1[tb] == θbDot1, 
      θDot1[tf] == θfDot1,
      θDot2[tb] == θbDot2, 
      θDot2[tf] == θfDot2
    },
    {c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}];
   First@(θ[t] /. PolynomialParameter)
 ]
```

**Test**

```
polyInterpolation[0, 1, 4, 2, 5, 5, 6, 4]
```

> ```
>   4 + 5 t + 3 t^2 - 77 t^3 + 110 t^4 - 43 t^5
> ```
>
> [image]

So using the style as below:

$$InterpolatingPolynomial[\{\{t_b, θ_b, θ'_b, θ''_b\}, \{t_f, θ_f, θ'_f, θ''_f\}\}, x]$$

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 5, 4}}, x] // Simplify
```

> ```
>  4 + 5 x + 3 x^2 - 77 x^3 + 110 x^4 - 43 x^5
> ```